# I can't change position of ImageView and setText of TextView

Tags: android

I have this code (for Android):

```
handler.post(new MyRunnable());
....
static public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            text.setText("Hi");
            imageV.layout(imageV.getLeft()+y, 218, imageV.getLeft()+150+y, 464);
            }
       }
```

Text is set, but position of `imageV` is not changed. When i don't write `text.setText("Hi");`, position will be changed. I have an `AbsoluteLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setLayoutParams`

```
handler.post(new MyRunnable());
....
static public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        text.setText("Hi");
        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) imageV.getLayoutParams();
        params.left += y;
        params.top = 218;
        params.right = params.left + 150;
        params.bottom = 464;
        imageV.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
 }
```

Have in mind that you can use `view.getLeft()` and so on after at least one layout pass has been made. Before that this will return 0. If you want to do it via layout that won't do. You have to also call requestLayout(). But calling layout + requestLayout() is pretty much what the implementation of setLayoutParams does anyway, so you're better off using it instead.

Comment: I don't know if I'm right, but when I start event manager I will see that this implementation is more complicated(6-10x)(in my program) for CPU. Thing number two: I don't understand why i can't use setText and then layout in Relative/AbosoluteLayoute and i try to use requestLayout() too. Because I don't want to change the margins of the View, but I want to set position(x,y) of View. Is there any other way? Thanks for every help!

Comment: The only way to change the position of the view and change its touch area as well(the place where it will receive touch evnets) is via setLayoutParams. The other way I'm aware of is to override the onDraw/dispatchDraw method of your view and call `canvas.translate(x,y)` before calling `super.dispatchDraw()`. Then the view will be 'moved' but it will be only visually. The view will continue receiving touch events on its old spot(the place of its left and top margin). Why are you reluctant to use setLayoutParams?